# How do I use a while loop with a macro?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, elisp-macros, defmacro

This works when I remove the loop but with the loop it does not
work.

```lisp
(defmacro my/def-key (state map)
  (let ((x '(
              (kbd "<leader>z z") (lambda nil (interactive)(message "zz"))
              (kbd "<leader>z f") (lambda nil (interactive)(message "zf")) 
              )))
    ;; works
    ;;`(evil-define-key ,state ,map ,(pop x) ,(pop x))

    ;; Don't work
    (while x 
      `(evil-define-key ,state ,map ,(pop x) ,(pop x)))))

(my/def-key 'normal global-map )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A macro has to build and return code, it doesn’t execute anything directly. Your body of your `while` loop does indeed build some code, but the `while` itself throws that code away and returns nil. Thus your macro “expands” to nothing at all. You can use `macroexpand` and `macroexpand-1` to debug this sort of thing; evaluating `(macroexpand-1` (my/def-key 'normal ,global-map))` would reveal the problem.

I recommend using `mapcar` or `cl-map` to walk over the list and accumulate the results in a new list that you can return.

Like this:

```lisp
(defmacro my/def-key (state map)
  (let* ((definitions '(((kbd "<leader>z z") (lambda nil (interactive) (message "zz")))
                        ((kbd "<leader>z f") (lambda nil (interactive) (message "zf")))))
         (body (mapcar
                (lambda (def)
                  `(evil-define-key ,state ,map ,(car def) ,(cadr def)))
                definitions)))
    `(progn ,@body)))
```

Comment: Thanks well explained, however not sure how to go about it. I tried this, almost close: `(cl-mapcar (lambda (_)(interactive) (evil-define-key ,state ,map ,(pop x) ,(pop x)))   x )` Evil function has a backtick.

Comment: Thanks for your help I think I figured it out.